# Understanding Try/Finally Suppressed Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, try-catch-finally

I'm learning Exceptions and I found out that you can have suppressed ones.
I read many examples on stackoverflow but still, they don't work as they are supposed to in the "try/finally" case:

```
public class MultipleExceptionsExample {

   static class IOManip implements Closeable{
       @Override
       public void close() {
           throw new RuntimeException("from IOManip.close");
       }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       try(IOManip ioManip = new IOManip()){
           throw new RuntimeException("from try!");
       }catch(Exception e){
           throw new RuntimeException("from catch!");
       }finally{
           throw new RuntimeException("from finally!");
       }
   }
}
```

As many explain, with all lines I should get: "java.lang.RuntimeException: from finally!" (Yes I do)

Removing finally block I should get: "java.lang.RuntimeException: from catch!" (Yes I do)

Removing catch block I should get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: from try!
    Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: from IOManip.close
```

And I never do! Why? What am I missing?

By removing the catch block I should see the try message, but I get this instead:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: from finally!
    at it.core.MultipleExceptionsExample.main(MultipleExceptionsExample.java:18)
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The throw in the finally block hides - completely replaces - the previously-thrown exception.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Have you recompiled your code after removing the finally and the catch blocks?

Comment: More details [here](https://errorprone.info/bugpattern/Finally)

Comment: Oh wait, you remove the catch and not the finally? Then @AndyTurner's is the answer.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ the trick is that OP apparently never removed the finally block, which is very unclear.

Comment: @f1sh right, I thought he was removing both catch and finally when I wrote the first comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A return or throw in a `finally` block causes any other returned (or thrown) result to be ignored.

Don't `return` or `throw` in a `finally` block, unless you *really* know what you're doing.

It should be noted that Java Throwables have a notion of "suppressed" exceptions: you can invoke [`addSuppressed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed(java.lang.Throwable)) on a `Throwable` that you have caught; this is done automatically with a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block, if an exception occurs in the body *and* whilst closing the resource; but this does not happen for a throw in a `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `finally` block would always execute. It doesn't matter if you catch the exception or not. To understand it better try the code bellow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (IOManip ioManip = new IOManip()) {
        System.out.println("Try!");
        throw new RuntimeException("from try!");
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Finally!");
    }
}
```

Remember that it is not a good practice to return or throw from the finally block, and you should avoid doing that.